# Redirect in Javascript with multiple query params

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this code :

```
if($('#category').val() == 4){
   console.log("http://"+window.location.hostname+'/dailyGift?id_event='+$( "#sub-category" ).val()+'?week_id='+$('#week_id').val()+'?year_id='+$('#year_id').val());
   window.location = "http://"+window.location.hostname+'/dailyGift?id_event='+$( "#sub-category" ).val()+'?week_id='+$('#week_id').val()+'?year_id='+$('#year_id').val();
}
```

In the console I have

```
http://myWebsite.dev/dailyGift?id_event=41?week_id=44?year_id=2016.
```

When I access directly works without problems, but jQuery does not make this redirect and I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: When you have fixed the &, what does the console say?

Comment: @mplungjan : `http://myWebsite.dev/dailyGift?id_event=41&week_id=44&year_id=2016`

Comment: But I'm not redirected to this page :(

Comment: Any error messages in the console? Does the URL work when pasted into the location bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change all the `?` with `&` except the first one

```
if($('#category').val() == 4){
   console.log("http://"+window.location.hostname+'/dailyGift?id_event='+$( "#sub-category" ).val()+'&week_id='+$('#week_id').val()+'&year_id='+$('#year_id').val());
}
```

Comment: Works but not all the time

Comment: `window.location = "http://"+window.location.hostname+'/dailyGift?id_event='+$( "#sub-category" ).val()+'&week_id='+$('#week_id').val()+'&year_id='+$('#year_id').val();`

Comment: Also be consistent with the quotes `var URL = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/dailyGift"+
  "?id_event="+$("#sub-category").val()+
  "&week_id="+$("#week_id").val()+
  "&year_id="+$("#year_id").val();

`

Answer (score 1):

Please replace all "?" with "&", Correct URL would be :-

http://myWebsite.dev/dailyGift?id_event=41&week_id=44&year_id=2016

Also it would be good if you encrypt ids for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to redirect to a link but you're merely changing the location.href value which is equivalent to clicking a link.

[Location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) will load the new resource in place of the current one. The current page will not be added to the session history so it will not be possible to return to it using the back button.

I've also cleaned up the use of " and ' in the url string to make it cleaner.

```
if ($('#category').val() == 4){
  var url = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/dailyGift?id_event="+$('#sub-category').val()+"&week_id="+$('#week_id').val()+"&year_id="+$('#year_id').val();
  console.log(url);
  window.location.replace(url);
}
```